# How to use cd with shell variable containing spaces

Tags: command-line, bash

I am trying to create an environment variable for a path that is long, has a space, and syntax.

I tried the following:

```
export temp=/Users/username/Dropbox (Personal)
```

And added it to my .profile.

I also tried:

```
export temp='/Users/username/Dropbox (Personal)'
export temp="/Users/username/Dropbox (Personal)"
export temp=/Users/username/Dropbox\ \(Personal\)
```

None of the above work. My end goal is to type `cd $temp` or `cp $temp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use wildcards:

```
export temp="/Users/username/Dropbox??Personal?"
```

or:

```
export temp="/Users/username/Dropbox*Personal*"
```

Now, `cd $temp` should work.

Answer (score 12):

Besides the first assignment, all three work in assigning the correct value to `$temp`. But due to the way `bash` parses the command line, you need to write

```
cd "$temp"
```

afterwards to make it work (which also means that it is a good idea to always use `"$var"` in shell scripts).

It might be easier in your case to make an alias with

```
alias cdtemp='cd "/Users/username/Dropbox (Personal)"'
```

for use with `cd`.

For `cp` you still need to add the "" though. To avoid this, either name your folders without using characters with special meaning to the shell or create a symlink with `ln -s ~/"Dropbox (Personal)" ~/DP`.

Comment: I'd considered "$temp" but it seems a little less simple than what I wanted. An alias command notwithstanding is there any alternative that would allow me to use $temp (without quotes"?

Comment: Use folder names without characters having special meaning for the shell (the space in your case). Or make a symlink with `ln -s ~/"Dropbox (Personal)" ~/DP` and use this afterwards.

Comment: `cd "${temp}"` is even better at making sure everything is correctly escaped.

Comment: @orkoden Using {} helps in separating the name of an variable from other text (which is not required here), it doesn't impact the interpretation of the content of the variable

Comment: It is a good point. Changing the folder to something without special characters is something I looked into. Dropbox doesn't seem to allow one to change the folder name (at this time).