# bash variable with spaces why cd "$myvar" results in one parameter, but myvar='"some stuff"' in two?

Tags: bash

I'm struggling to understand why following does not work as expected in `bash`:

```
$ myvar='"some stuff"'
$ echo $myvar
"some stuff"
$ cd $myvar
bash: cd: "some: No such file or directory
```

I know the `canonical` way is to ([How to use cd with shell variable containing spaces](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218518/how-to-use-cd-with-shell-variable-containing-spaces)):

```
$ myvar="some stuff"
$ echo $myvar
some stuff
$ cd "$myvar"
```

But e.g. here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12258418/881191 answer by Alex for macOS advices to escape quotations, which I also tried and it's the same as putting double quotations inside single ones in my case. Why in one case `cd` gets two parameters and in other two from as I see it same "some stuff"?

Comment: The shell parses quotes and escapes before expanding variable references, so if you put a quote in a variable, by the time it's part of the command it's too late for it to work normally. See: [Why does shell ignore quotes in arguments passed to it through variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-shell-syntax-in-arguments-passed-via-variables) BTW, the reason embedding quotes worked in the answer you linked is that that's an *alias*, not a variable, and quotes do get parsed after aliases are expanded.

Comment: @ Gordon, thank you! will you write it as answer so I can upvote?

Comment: This part of shell syntax confuses a lot of people, so there are are a lot of questions about it already. Lots are on stackoverflow (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49840808/cd-doesnt-work-in-script-with-quotes)), and a few here on AskDifferent as well ([this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218518/how-to-use-cd-with-shell-variable-containing-spaces) and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301596/storing-a-directory-name-with-spaces-in-a-bash-variable)), so I think it's better to mark this as a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, quotes are strip in a parameter/variable assignment, unless the quotes them self are quoted and they then become part of the string. As in your example `"some stuff"` is the string attached to `$myvar`. When you issue the command-

```
cd $myvar
```

the command is broken up into tokens- words and operators. The shell parses them into a command and arguments, then parameter/variable expansion takes place on `$myvar`. Since `$myvar` isn't quoted the contents are split into two words (known as field or word splitting) -

```
"some and stuff"
```

Thus, the error message- `bash: cd: "some: No such file or directory`. Since `cd` only accepts one argument `stuff"` is disregarded.
Even when you quote the variable `$myvar` it still produces an error message because the directory name is some stuff not "some stuff"-

```
cd "$myvar" 
bash: cd: "some stuff": No such file or directory
```